# Read xml from batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am trying to read an xml file using a batch (.bat) file and have searched multiple sites without a successful solution.

XML file structure:

```
<parameter>
<name>myname</name>
<value>1234</value>
</parameter>
```

Attempted batch code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%i in ('type "sample.xml" ^|find "myname"') do set "value=%%i"
echo %value%
```

... And then repeats with each one having its own name and value.

What I want to do is get the value using the name as the search criteria.

I can't share what I have tried as I am using my phone to send this.

Comment: If it's _always_ going to be in the format `<name>value</name>` and there is no possibility that that line would ever contain newlines, then simply running a `find` for `name` through a `for /f` loop and using `delims=<>` can get you the value. If you think there's even the slightest chance that the format of your data will deviate from what you've posted, use a language that can actually parse XML.

Comment: Thanks, I can find and get the name, but no idea how to get the value from it.

Comment: Original message updated with attempted code.

Comment: Your attempted code works correctly for me (assuming that `SipUserId` is either the field name or the value of the `name` field). Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error. It's returning the name "SipUserId", but I need the value that belongs to that name. In the example I have myname (aka SipUserId), but I need it to return the value (1234)... I updated the code to match the sample.

Comment: Oh jeez, I completely misread your question. The bad news is that this is complicated, but the good news is that there are several hundred questions on here about how to parse XML in batch. Even better news is that both powershell and vbscript come with all versions of Windows and both have native XML parsing support.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Appreciated. Looking at alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The core point of your problem is that you want to get *the **next** line* after the one you located. There are *a lot* of methods to achieve this. The next one is a pretty simple one:

```
for /F "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N "myname" sample.xml') do set "lines=%%i"
for /F "skip=%lines% tokens=2 delims=<>" %%v in (sample.xml) do set "value=%%v" & goto next
:next
echo %value%
```

Of course, if the .xml file have a different format, this method will not work...

---

Here it is a complete test. THis is the program  **test.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /I /N "%~1" sample.xml') do set "lines=%%i"
for /F "skip=%lines% tokens=2 delims=<>" %%v in (sample.xml) do set "value=%%v" & goto next
:next
echo %value%
```

This is the **sample.xml** file I used in the test:

```
<parameter>
<name>myName</name>
<value>Antonio</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>myDate</name>
<value>2022/02/24</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
<name>myTime</name>
<value>12:13:14</value>
</parameter>
```

And this is the test:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> test myName
Antonio

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> test myDate
2022/02/24

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test> test myTime
12:13:14
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, I actually tried that but now winning. I just came back in to ask about this exact process but I'm not getting any results. I also tried to force a specific line, but still not showing any data.

Comment: If I echo the line number that I'm searching for, it shows the correct line number, but it's not showing the result of the next line or any hard codes line I set.

Comment: I've looked around and tried other methods... Is there no way to read the file as raw text to extract the full line then simply remove any unwanted code?

Comment: nope - not with batch anyway. Powershell is able to do so and it has full REGEX support to extract the desired data.

Comment: You must enter the variable name with the same case than the data (the same point apply to your code) **or** add **/I** in FINDSTR command in order to ignore the case. See the edit in my answer. Perhaps if you post a small segment of the **real file** you are using, we could help you better...